# Have anybody tested R multicore packages on 10-core Xeon how do they scale in comparison with case of 4 core machine?

Tags: performance, multi-core, r, xeon

Have anybody tested R multicore packages (for example : parallel, multicore, snowfall, foreach) on 10-core Xeon ? How do they scale in comparison with case of 4 core machine ? What algorith have you paralized mayby some MCMC ?

Is it right forum, or stakoverflow is more suitable for my question ?

Comment: Looks like stackoverflow is more suitable.